# Passing session to backgroundTask cherrypy

Tags: python, web-applications, cherrypy

I am having trouble correctly configuring my function for my background task to take in cherrypy. I want the background task to use session data, be able to regenerate the current session and also expire the session.

this is an example of what im trying

```
import cherrypy
import cherrypy.process.plugins

class MainApp(object):

    def signin(self,user,pass):
        cherrypy.session['username'] = username
        cherrypy.session['password']  = password

    def communicateWithServer(self):
        user = cherrypy.session.get('username')
        password = cherrypy.session.get('password')
        response = requests.get("http://someserver/api?username="+user+"&password="+password)

    cherrypy.process.plugins.BackgroundTask(600, communicateWithServer (object)).start()
```

but then I get this error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 34, in <module>
    class MainApp(object):
  File "main.py", line 202, in MainApp
    cherrypy.process.plugins.BackgroundTask(600, communicateWithServer(object)).start()
  File "main.py", line 191, in loginReport
    user = cherrypy.session.get('username')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'session'
```

What is the correct method of passing sessions to a backgroundTask?

Comment: `cherrypy.session` is a thread-local and it is bound to the user's request, thus only available during HTTP request-response flow.
Could you please specify which high-level task are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to use the session to store the username and password to repeatedly contact a login server to ensure the user shown as online to other users. I can achieve this saving data to a file but thought sessions would be more eligant.

Comment: You cannot use sessions this way. You might want to use smth like a Redis store for this.

Comment: P.S. Feel free to ask your question on [gitter](https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy), perhaps others may suggest something better than this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since sessions can not be used as I originally intending I am using a sqlite3 data base instead to store the data that would have been in the session and then communicating with the server from there.